# Woosim SDK for Android 2.2

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to get the SDK for the Woosim Portable Printers for a project but i can't find them anywhere! You guys know where i can find those (SDK and sample code)!? I tried the home site but, no luck.

I'm using a Woosim Porti-S30/40.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got them! For those o want them, you can download from this [link!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wi1y9omfv9njcn/%28Android2.2_bt%29_Eng%20%5B12.03.07%5D.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Where did you find them? I assume these will have been updated now but can't find them anywhere.

Comment: I had to contact them personally so they could give me the driver. I don't know if they updated them.

Comment: Did they also give the iOS sample project?

Comment: No sorry, i just asked for the android version.

Comment: @PedroCabo Hi. The link is broken. can you upload the Sdk again? Thanks!

Comment: @dor506 Already updated the link! Tell me if you can access it.

Comment: @PedroCabo It is working. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroCabo I'm having trouble printing image. Did you succeed doing so?

Comment: @dor506 oh i never tried to print any images using it, but check if you are using the correct file type and color depth, try using 8 bit or lower.